# Eclipse: Junit I am seeing this error in junit tab below

Tags: java, eclipse, testing, junit, initialization

Below is my simple code

```
package M06;

    public class ExerciseE03 {

        public double calcTotal (double total, boolean existingMember, boolean validDiscount, boolean validCoupon) {

            double discount=0.0;

            if (existingMember && validDiscount || validCoupon) {
                if (total > 1_000.0)
                    discount = 0.15;
                else
                    if (total >= 750)
                        discount = 0.1;
                    else
                        if (total > 500)
                            discount = 0.05;
                        else
                            discount = 0.025;
            }
            return (total * (1-discount) * 1.0825);
        }
    }
```

and this is the j unit file

```
package M06;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static junitparams.JUnitParamsRunner.$;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import junitparams.FileParameters;

public class ExerciseE03Test {
    private ExerciseE03 object;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        object = new ExerciseE03();
    }

    @Test
    @FileParameters("src/M06/E03TestCaseTable.csv")
    public void test(int testcaseNumber, boolean member, boolean disc, boolean coupon, double total, double discount, double output) {
        //ExerciseE03 object = new ExerciseE03();
        //assertEquals(1380.1875, object.calcTotal(1500, true, true, true),0.001);
        object.calcTotal( total, member, disc, coupon);
        assertEquals(output,object.calcTotal(total, member, disc, coupon),0.01);
    }

}
```

I am also providing my junit screenshot below. since i am new to juint, i don't know what are steps to be taken for this type of error

[image]

Above is the error that i can see in my junit tab below.

Comment: write your error's message in the post. don't upload error's image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the @RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class) annotation on the top of your test class, ExerciseE03Test.

```
@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class)
public class ExerciseE03Test {
```

Check this [post](https://www.baeldung.com/junit-params) to learn more.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, yes this helped me to solve the problem. reallt thanks really new to it just started it. Do you have any idea how to make jacoco test coverage on this

Comment: This post can help. https://www.baeldung.com/jacoco. If you are looking for eclipse plugin, check this out https://www.eclemma.org/